# How can I turn a pandas.core.series.Series into a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I turn this pandas.core.series.Series into a dataframe?

At the moment it looks like this:

```
A    [0.18, 0.14, 0.22]
B    [0.82, 0.78, 0.86]
C    [0.03, 0.01, 0.04]
D    [0.17, 0.13, 0.2]
```

I'd like to create a Dataframe with three columns called "V1", "V2", "V3" so that each value of each row goes in the right column.

In the end in my Dataframe row A should be V1= 0.18, V2= 0.14, V3=0.22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do

```
out = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index = s.index)
```